# Google Maps and java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, google-maps, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api, socket-timeout-exception

The code below has a few issues. First, it's giving me a SocketTimeoutException. This was working just fine a few days ago, but now it's throwing this error. I'm not sure how to trace the problem to the source. I tried increasing the timeout (which I really don't think will work in the end), but it always times out after 18 seconds. What's more strange is that the URL works when I try getting a JSON file from something else (such as http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json). I've waited about a day and the issue is still there. Is there anything I could do to resolve this issue?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class SocketTimeoutError {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        URL myURL;
        TimerTask task = null;
        try {
            myURL = new URL(
                    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Chicago+Illinois");

            URLConnection conn = myURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(4 * 600000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(4 * 600000);
            //
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            task = new TimerTask() {
                int time = 0;

                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(time++);
                }
            };
            //
            System.out.println("Connecting..." + "Timeout="
                    + conn.getConnectTimeout());
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            task.cancel();
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(in);
            String status = (String) jsonObject.get("status");
            System.out.println(status);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my console output:

```
Connecting...Timeout=2400000
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at SocketTimeoutError.main(SocketTimeoutError.java:38)
```

---Edit---

I've been doing this on my work machine. I just tried this code on my home computer and it works just fine. Also, the company I work for has a Google for Work license. I don't understand how it could be a network issue, though, between the company and the google servers, because I'm able to view the json in my Chrome browser.

Comment: I would say there might be something going on in your companies firewall, your client agent from your java code might looks suspicious to your network admin, and they might blocked your traffic in order to protect the Google for Work licence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what the issue was. I had to connect through a proxy (which our browsers automatically do and explains why I got a response when I used a web browser). I just had to modify my code in the following way:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.url.com", 80));
URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection(proxy);
```